# What is the Best way to show 4 types of buy button in app

Tags: user-behavior, guidelines, ux-designer, visual-design, graphic-design

This is educational app. Some products having 3 or 4 buttons, example **( Buy e- book, Rental e-book, Buy Chapters, Buy Combo)** What is the Best way to show this button in app.

IMAGE attached ( landscape mode )

[image]

Comment: This is an ebook. Singal chapter also can buy with 90% discount
Buy combo On this you can get multiple books in single click only

Answer (score 2):

Four types of buy button? I think we've found the problem. :)

Think about having just one Buy button, and providing buy options: EBook, Rent, Buy Chapters, and Buy Combo.

The analog would be buying shoes online: There's just one Buy (or Add to Cart) button but before you can do that you have to specify size, width, color, etc.

Comment: yes, i think so. What the hell is a combo anyway? Has there been research that users actually need to buy chapters .... or rent an ebook? Who the hell rents a book? Are you a library? lol.

Comment: If the price for rental is super low compared to buying, then it may entice people who'd rather rent it for a few days/week and then lose access. I assume this is meant for students who often only need a select few chapters opposed to the whole book (at least that happened a lot in my experience). We just had professors who'd just print the chapter for us to save us a hundred for the whole textbook.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ken's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/119482/57088) (select what you want, *then* "Buy" it), I think you would benefit if you made the various options more "dynamic"...

- If you select to buy or rent the e-book, then (I presume) you get all chapters. If so, then by all means *list* the chapters if you think it useful, but you should disable the ability to select the chapters<sup>**1**</sup>.
- If, as in your example, the user is in "chapter mode" but has not selected any chapter, the "Buy" button should be disabled (there's nothing to buy!)
- If "Rent e-book" doesn't mean "the whole thing", and you can, in fact, rent individual chapters, then instead of three buttons/options for "Buy e-book", "Rent e-book" and "Buy chapters", you probably want two independent selectors:

  - Buy or rent
  - Whole book or chapters

(I've ignored "Buy combo" because I don't know what it means... fit it into the above as appropriate).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> You could choose to *hide* the check-boxes, relying on the "Buy e-book" to imply "all chapters". If you choose to keep them visible-but-disabled, then I would suggest you remember the user's current selection before auto-ticking them.

The reason: the user might have started in "chapter" mode and selected a number of chapters. Presumably, at some point it will become cheaper to get the whole e-book instead of individual chapters (or, at least, the difference becomes small enough to justify getting the whole book instead of only parts). Near that point<sup>**2**</sup>, the user might click "Buy e-book" to see how much it would be. If they don't like the price, and return to "chapter mode", it would be nice if you restore their previous selection.

<sup>**2**</sup> For bonus points (and possible "up-sell"), you could monitor how many chapters the user has selected and display a message along the lines of "*For only £xx.xx more you can buy the whole e-book!*".